# Unable to display Profile image in nav header with Firebase Database

Tags: android, image, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, user-profile

Firebase having problem displaying the image uploaded on the Firebase database. Looking the variables with the debug it seems there is the URL of the image but it doesn't show on the Navigation header when i run the app. Like this: [that image is the placeholder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3L21P.jpg)

[these are the variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNaQ9.png)

this is the code

```
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    UserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    currentUserID = Objects.requireNonNull(mAuth.getCurrentUser()).getUid();

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("ES     ");
    toolbar.setTitleTextAppearance(this, R.style.toolbar_textAppearance);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    NavProfileImage = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
    NavTextView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.text_Nickname);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    UserRef.child(currentUserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                Log.d("image Path", NavProfileImage.toString());
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("nickname")) {
                    String nickname = dataSnapshot.child("nickname").getValue(String.class);
                    NavTextView.setText(nickname);
                }
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("profileImage")) {
                    String image = dataSnapshot.child("profileImage").getValue(String.class);
                    Picasso.get().load(image).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(NavProfileImage);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Profile name do not exists...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: [mcve] perhaps ?

Comment: Are you sure that the link that of your photo is correct? If you try to open in a broser does it work?

Comment: It seems that that the url for retrieving image is invalid.